# Behavior when fetching const ptr from string stringstream

Tags: c++, string, vector

I have the following piece of code, for which i am trying to understand its behavior :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

void fill(std::vector<const char *> & vec, string str) {
   uint32_t start_count = 1;
   stringstream regname;
   for(uint32_t count = 0; count <= 3; count++) {
      regname.str("");
      regname << str << (uint32_t)(count + start_count);
      std::cout << "regname : " << regname.str() << std::endl;
      vec.push_back(regname.str().c_str());
   }
}

int main() {
   vector<const char *> vec;
   fill(vec, "temp");

   for(int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
      std::cout << "value at index : " << i << " is  : " << vec[i] << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Initial string in the vector are printed correctly, however for strings initialized in fill method i get all the instances with "temp4" which is the last initialized string.
O/P when using std::vector of const char * :

```
regname : temp1
regname : temp2
regname : temp3
regname : temp4
value at index : 0 is  : temp4
value at index : 1 is  : temp4
value at index : 2 is  : temp4
value at index : 3 is  : temp4
```

This behavior is corrected when i try to use std::vector instead.
O/P when using std::vector of string object :

```
regname : temp1
regname : temp2
regname : temp3
regname : temp4
value at index : 0 is  : temp1
value at index : 1 is  : temp2
value at index : 2 is  : temp3
value at index : 3 is  : temp4
```

Just wanted to know what is causing this behavior ?

Comment: Use `std::vector<std::string>` and `vec.push_pack(regname.str())` to make your pain go away. Also just use a `count` from `1` to `4` instead of that silly addition.

Answer (score 4):

Calling `str` on regname will return a string copy of the streams contents. Calling `c_str` on that string will return a pointer to an array that contains the sequence of characters in that string.

Apparently, the pointer you push back to this array is the same for all 4 loop iterations and printing them after calling the `fill` method will print the same contents four times.

Your current code is unsafe as the strings are temporaries within your fill method and the pointers to their internal character arrays will dangle after returning from `fill`. Better use strings in you `vec` vector to store real copies.

Comment: But when i am pushing the same into a vector, wont it create a different instance of the pointer. Even if i declare the stringstream inside the loop , result remains the same.

Comment: It will make a copy of the pointer, not of the data at the location your pointer points to.

Comment: Who keeps teaching pointers so poorly that people feel the need to store them long-term and think that they "are" strings? :(

Answer (score 0):

Before `push_back()`, allocate memory dynamically to preserve it after function's callframe is cleared. Something like below (See http://ideone.com/aR0f98 demo)

```
#include <cstring>

...
char * p = new char[regname.str().length() + 1];
strcpy(p, regname.str().c_str());
vec.push_back(p);
```

Remember to delete it after it is used to prevent memory leaks. However, this is **NOT** recommended. Use of `std::string` is recommended here.